smtp server error tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
I bought a ubuntu vps from contabo and trying to create an smtp server using aapanel i watched this guy on youtube and i followed every steps. Now i am able to send mails from my custom domain using thunderbird. However i am trying to send mails programmatically using Go. I tried to send email from windows using this code.
package main

import (
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/gomail.v2"
)

func main() {

    smtpServer := "mydomain.com"
    smtpPort := 587
    smtpUser := "noreply@mydomain.com"
    smtpPassword := "mypassword"

    from := "mydomain <noreply@mydomain.com>"
    to := "reciever@gmail.com"

    m := gomail.NewMessage()
    m.SetHeader("From", from)
    m.SetHeader("To", to)
    m.SetHeader("Subject", "Test Email")
    m.SetBody("text/html", `<html><body><h1>Hello, World!</h1><p>This is a test  email.</p></body></html>`)

    d := gomail.NewDialer(smtpServer, smtpPort, smtpUser, smtpPassword)

    if err := d.DialAndSend(m); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to send email: %v", err)
    }

    log.Println("Email sent successfully")
}


On windows i can send mails but same code does not work on my ubuntu pc. The error i got is
tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority.
Some people says my ssl certificate is not public but i checked mydomain using this website and mydomain's get A+ as score.
Also i run openssl s_client -connect mydomain.com:587 -starttls smtp on my pc and i got
depth=0 CN = *.mydomain.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = *.mydomain.com
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1

I really do not know what to do. I would be appreciate for any answer. Thank you.
